# Alert con ajax en c#

Tags: c#, ajax

Buenas , me gustaría saber como puedo hacer aparecer un alert al pulsar un botón,  pero con ajax(utilizando jquery mejor) , es decir sin que me recargue la página.
El código que tengo ahora con el que me recarga la pagina es el siguiente:

```
     protected void btn_cambiarContra_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
        if (nuevo_Password.Text==repetir_Password.Text)
        {


            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"myScript", "<script>alert('Las contraseñas coinciden');</script>");

        }else
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", "<script>alert('Las contraseñas NO coinciden');</script>");
        }
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hazlo desde el cliente utiliza el evento onclick del botón:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn_cambiarContra").click(function () {
        if($("#nuevo_Password").val() == $("#repetir_Password").val()){
            alert('Las contraseñas coinciden');
        }
        else{
            alert('Las contraseñas NO coinciden');
        }
    });
});
```